# Redirect from http to https in Spring Boot 2.0.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, https

I use `Spring boot 2.0.4`. I want to configure auto redirect from http to https for all url patterns. I add in my application.yml this lines:

```
server:
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-alias: tomcat
    key-store: "classpath:tomcat.keystore"
    key-store-type: jks
    key-store-password: 123456
    key-password: 123456
```

And I created bean:

```
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory httpsRedirectConfig() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory () {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
    }
```

But, When I run my application, I have error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to multiple ServletWebServerFactory beans : tomcatServletWebServerFactory,httpsRedirectConfig
```

What is wrong? How I can fix it? Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with below configurations.

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector redirectConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector(
            TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    return connector;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. In browser I have error: Bad Request
This combination of host and port requires TLS.

Comment: And `security.require-ssl` don't exist in `Spring Boot 2`!

Comment: it is because you cannot serve both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port.

Comment: Actually I am getting error "javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Tomcat:type=Connector,port=8080, The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start."
I checked 8080 port is not used by any other application. Even if I use server.port = 8080 in application.properties it works.
But if I use it in ur code it doesnt work and throws error.